# command error after start project in django

Tags: python, django-upgrade

After upgrading my django from 1.8 to 1.10, when i start a project(django-admin startproject lwc) there is an error:

`CommandError: C:\Python34\binesh\lwc\lwc\settings.py already exists,` overlaying
a project or app into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files.
it creates a file for lwc, `manage.py` and another lwc folder in it, and settings.py in second lwc folder.

what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall django, delete your python/Lib/site-packages/django directory completely, then reinstall.

The installation of the new version, even though it claims to uninstall the old version, leaves old files hanging around, and they are quietly brought into the new version in  various ways (e.g., manage.py can bring in syncdb if a sync.py is left over in the django directories).

Answer (score 0):

You might have Django installed twice. Running "pip uninstall django" twice, and then reinstalling new version again should help.

Comment: when is run pip freeze i have one django.